# Permission denied on MAKE TEST

Tags: makefile, redis

Does anyone know why in the process of installing `Redis` I get these errors when running `make test` after I already ran `sudo apt install build-esential`

```
$ make test
cd src && make test
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/alek/redis-6.0.8/src'
touch: cannot touch 'release.h': Permission denied
...
touch: cannot touch 'release.c': Permission denied
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
...
    CC Makefile.dep
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create Makefile.dep: Permission denied
...
echo STD=-std=c11 -pedantic -DREDIS_STATIC='' >> .make-settings
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create .make-settings: Permission denied
```

If this helps:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Who's the owner of `redis-6.0.8/src`? Did you clone/untar the source as root?

Comment: First try (with same error) was in `mnt/c/Users/ubuntuusername`,  now its just `ubuntu@PCusername:~/redis-6.0.8$`

Comment: I installed many packages the 1 thing left is ```~/redis-6.0.8/src$ touch Makefile.dep
touch: cannot touch 'Makefile.dep': Permission denied```   (i try to manually install bcuz `make test` couldnt, i even open ubuntu `Run as Administrator`

Comment: **Update** i used `sudo make test` and it runs the test... Cool! How can i set root permissions tho?

Comment: @Aleksandar To permanently change the owner of the directory to the current user, you can do `sudo chown -R "$(whoami)" ~/redis-6.0.8`. (Then you won't need to use `sudo` later).